# Application of Kirchoff's Matrix Tree Theorem

Tags: graph-theory, trees, algebraic-graph-theory

Calculate the number of spanning trees of the graph that you obtain by removing one edge from $K_n$.

(Hint: How many of the spanning trees of $K_n$ contain the edge?)

Can anyone please help me out here?

Comment: The gist is: For each edge $e$ of $K_n$, the number of spanning trees of $K_n$ containing $e$ does not depend on $e$ (to prove this, pick any two edges $e$ and $f$ of $K_n$, and set up a bijection between the spanning trees containing $e$ and the spanning trees containing $f$). But the sum of these numbers is $n-1$ times the number of all spanning trees of $K_n$ (why?).

Comment: I notice that you deleted this question shortly after getting an answer. That is not very nice, especially toward your answerer. I've undeleted this question.

Answer (score 2):

By [Cayley's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_formula) or [Prufer encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_sequence) we have that the number of spanning trees of $K_n$ is $n^{n-2}$.
By [Kirchoff' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_theorem), the number of spanning trees in $K_n\setminus e$ is given by the determinant of the reduced Laplacian matrix of $K_n\setminus e$. The Laplacian matrix (in the $n=5$ case) has the following structure:
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
    n-2 & -1 & -1 & -1 & 0 \\
   -1 & n-1 & -1 & -1 & -1 \\
   -1 & -1 & n-1 & -1 & -1 \\
   -1 & -1 &  -1 & n-1 & -1 \\
    0 & -1 &  -1 & -1 & n-2 \end{pmatrix} $$
and a similar structure in the general case. By removing the last row&column, the problem boils down to computing the determinant of a $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ matrix with off-diagonal elements equal to $-1$ and diagonal elements equal to $n-2,n-1,\ldots,n-1$. By performing one step of Gaussian elimination and a Laplace expansion along the first row, the wanted number of spanning trees is so given by:
$$ \det\begin{pmatrix}n-1 & -n & 0 & 0 \\ -1 & n-1 & -1 & -1 \\ -1& -1 & n-1 & -1 \\ -1 & -1 & -1 & n-1\end{pmatrix}$$ 
that is simple to compute from the fact that the determinant of o $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ matrix with diagonal elements equal to $(n-1)$ and off-diagonal elements equal to $-1$ is $n^{n-2}$.

On the other hand, by Grinberg's remark the answer is given by $$n^{n-2}-(n-1)n^{n-2}\binom{n}{2}^{-1}=\color{red}{(n-2)n^{n-3}}.$$